# ASP.NET Core http post [FromBody] broken in 3.1, used to work in 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am having all kinds of errors migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2, to 3.1.

My latest error is that the object I am receiving via a Http Post is null.

Here is the code that receives the object, and in this case the model is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction([FromBody] BoardMoveModel model)
```

The model class:

```
public class BoardMoveModel
{
    public int BoardId { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public int DestinationStatusId { get; set; }
    public int SourceStatusId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SourceStatusList {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<int> DestinationStatusList {get; set;}
}
```

And the Javascript code:

```
        var data = {
            TicketId: el.id,
            DestinationStatusId: targetStatusId,
            SourceStatusId: sourceStatusId,
            SourceStatusList: sourceList,
            DestinationStatusList: destList
        };

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: "/Area/Board/MyAction",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken:
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).done(function(result) {
```

Here is the actual JSON Payload:

```
             {
                 "TicketId":"150",
                 "DestinationStatusId":"5",
                 "SourceStatusId":"6",
                 "SourceStatusList":[],
                 "DestinationStatusList":["140","150"]
             }
```

Comment: What is the actual JSON payload emitted by the javascript code?

Comment: Here is an example: {"Id":150,"Title":"title"}, but as I have mentioned this use to work, and since this has not changed, I suspect maybe that it is either some 3.1 thing or something that is not in the Startup... but I am yet to find it.

Comment: I asked because when I converted from 2.2 to 3.1, it balked about trailing commas in the JSON. Apparently that's not the issue here. 3.1 uses a different default JSON serializer. You can manually set it back to Newtonsoft and see if it works again.

Comment: What happens if in the JavaScript you change the keys from `Id` and `Title` to lowercase? I’m asking because IIRC when serializing ASP.Net Core makes the first character lower-case (camelCase) and it could be that the new serializer in 3.1 is not case-insensitive like the old one and expects camelCase when deserializing too. If that’s the case, it seems like a bug/regression.

Comment: I have updated the question with some missing information.
I suspect it is the IEnumarable, because if I remove it, the the model object is not null.

Comment: I dont get it... the whole object is null or just the list property? Also what is aList? we need to see the whole thing. The point is we need to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Give me a moment .. I'll get back to this in a bit. Fighting another issue... so many.

Comment: What @JasonSmith said. The JSON Serializer was changed. Try using JSON.NET again via `services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();` (add package first) and see if it happens again. New serializer uses new performance structures (Span<T>/Memory<T>, but has sophisticated features than Json.NET

Comment: Thank you @Tseng - I also totally rephrased my question, it was getting very messy.

Comment: I would try to set serializer to be case insensitive, . Probably after upgrading to .net core 3.1 this behavior was changed.

Comment: did you try what Tseng said? since the 2.2 uses the newtonsoftjson Microsoft pushed the new text.json in 3 which is not ready for production imo and might have different configuration, and there is no reference loop handling support yet

Comment: Ok this worked for me: 

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                }).AddNewtonsoftJson();

maybe setting the options is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is null because it's invalid for binding. In JSON you are passing in string values while model requires integers. Change either to match and it should work. *Binding is by default case sensitive, but it shouldn't be a problem with code you've provided.*

Try sending this as **application/json** body

```
{
    "TicketId":150,
    "DestinationStatusId":5,
    "SourceStatusId":6,
    "SourceStatusList":[],
    "DestinationStatusList":[140,150]
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked  - like a charm and so did AddNewtonsoftJson.

Comment: @Wayne Newtonsoft.Json gives more leeway with auto casting, but I'm not fan of the feature. It's merely a a safety net for poorly written code that mixes types. Unless you need it's advanced features, this extra dependency is better removed.